# NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app when sending push?

Tags: android-support-library, noclassdeffounderror, pushbots

Im using PushBots to manage my push notifications for my app, I have been using this amazing platform for lots of apps and its the first time I have a problem like this.

Sometimes, when I launch the app, I get this error, but always when receiving a push (within or whitout the app opened).

```
07-12 01:20:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(12140): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-326*****5*9-1]
07-12 01:20:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(12140): Process: com.karlol.mo***, PID: 12140
07-12 01:20:00.844: E/AndroidRuntime(12140): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat

> //This is just the beginning of the log, there's more with some
> Pushbots handler info and stuff.... Let me know if I need to post it,
> its a lot.
```

Im pretty sure this is about the android support v4, this is my current build path:

[image: Build Path]

*Sometimes when I uncheck the *Private Libraries* clean and re-check this option again the app works (but not lucky with notifications).

The support v4 jar is in the *libs* folder, the route is the correct (MyApp/libs)

Im about to release an update, my app is already working/running with pushbots servers (with registered devices and all) so I would like to solve this to release my update. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the android-support-v4.jar are you using? Also I see that there are two jars with the same name

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in these questions: [NotificationManagerCompat Can't be resolved - Android Wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577811/notificationmanagercompat-cant-be-resolved-android-wear) and [Android studio unable to import WearableExtender NotificationManagerCompat and RemoteInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677656/android-studio-unable-to-import-wearableextender-notificationmanagercompat-and-r). It seems that you are not using the last version of the compatibility support library. You have two options to solve that:

1. Download the newest libraries manually, and add them to your project.
2. It seems that you are using eclipse, I recommend that you now use  [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) so you can add the dependency and let gladle handle the libraries, like this

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0+'
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry Im using eclipse, I have downloaded the newest libraries (android support v4 jar) and nothing changed

Comment: Some years ago, I also used eclipse for some android projects, and I ran into the same problems for no explainable reason at that time. The good thing about Android Studio, is that integrates gradle so you don't have exactly this type of problems.

Comment: I entered by mistake the intro key. Have you tried cleaning the project with Project > Clean?

Comment: I have tried everithing in the world haha, how can I exactly check the v4 support version? And Im afraid of migrating to android studio, I would prefer start all over and thats why I dont do it.

Comment: I see here a similar question to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577811/notificationmanagercompat-cant-be-resolved-android-wear

Comment: Thanks. At the end it was the v4 version, Im using an old version of eclipse so the SDK manager didnt actually tell me the most recent version. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check mark the following jars in build path or property ,it will work
1. android-support-v4.jar(appcombat/ibs)
2.android-support-v4-appcombat.jar(appcombat/ibs)

Comment: If i ckeck this option i get the "No dex files" error or something like that.